# better way to get results

Tags: mysql, sql

Was wondering if there's a better way to run this query, since BETWEEN repeats it self, I only need to add a new rule `(and local=1)` OUTPUT is what I want, just wondering if there's a shorter or better version.

SCHEMA & RESULT: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e147c/2

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM orden WHERE actual_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-05' and local=1 and forma_pago='tarjeta' and status=4) as Principal 
FROM orden 
WHERE actual_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-05'
and forma_pago='tarjeta' 
and status=4
```

Comment: if any values of `actual_date` have time components, using `between` might cause you to miss records.

Comment: @DanBracuk tx for the tip, but that wont happen since `actual_date` only outputs that format `Y-m-d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
    , SUM(CASE
            WHEN local = 1 THEN 1
            ELSE 0
         END) AS Principal
FROM   orden
WHERE  actual_date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-01-05'
      AND forma_pago = 'tarjeta'
      AND status = 4;
```

sql Fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e147c/3